# How would I simulate TCP-RTM using/in NS2?

Tags: networking, tcp, real-time, ns2

Here is a paper named "[TCP-RTM: Using TCP for Real Time Multimedia Applications](http://gregorio.stanford.edu/sliang/rtm.pdf)" by [Sam Liang](http://gregorio.stanford.edu/sliang/), [David Cheriton](http://www.forbes.com/profile/david-cheriton/).

This paper is to adapt tcp to be used in Real time application. 
The two major modification which i actually want you to help me are:

1. On application-level read on the TCP connection, if there is no in sequence data queued to read but one or more out-of-order packets are queued for the connection, the first contiguous range of out-of-order packets is moved from the out-of-order queue to the receive queue, the receive pointer is advanced beyond these packets, and the resulting data delivered to the application. On reception of an out-of-order packet with a sequence number logically greater than the current receive pointer (rcv next ptr) and with a reader waiting on the connection, the packet data is delivered to the waiting receiver, the receive pointer is advanced past this data and this new receive pointer is
   returned in the next acknowledgment segment.
2. In the case that the sender’s send-buffer is full due to large amount of backlogged data, TCP-RTM discards the oldest data segment in the buffer and accepts the new data written by the application. TCP-RTM also advances its send-window past the discarded data segment. This way, the application write calls are never blocked and the timing of the sender application is not broken.

They actually changed the 'tcpreno with sack' version of tcp in an old linux 2.2 kernel in real environment.
But, I want to simulate this in [NS2](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/).
I can work with NS2 e.g., analyzing, making performance graphs etc. I looked all the related files but can't find where to change.
So, would you please help me to do this.